# How NLB will work with IIS-7 web services ?

Tags: web-services, networking, iis-7, nlb

We'are going to join 2 (two) IIS7 web-servers into NLB with the same web-service published (2 instances of the same web-service one per web-server).

- Do I understand correctly, that NLB will work for my web-services, deligating web-requests to one or another instance?
- How will NLB work if one of web-service instance becomes unavailable (i.e. starts to throw SOAP exceptions or HTTP errors)?
- Will NLB take into account the average web-service response time to decide web-service instance to deligate processing?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You'll be able to find the answers [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc738464%28WS.10%29.aspx)

But to help you ahead:

- Yes, it will distribute requests to both hosts
- No as long as there is a heartbeat (and that doesn't come from your app but from the NLB system itself)
- No